# How do I update a bigquery table with an array?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with the log data and I want to update it with the results from the subsequent query which will insert the results against the filtered row.

I want to use a union all to keep the current values and append the new ones but I get the following error:

> Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

```
UPDATE LOGGING.table_logs a
SET a.pinged = ARRAY(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT 
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as date,b.size_bytes,timestamp_millis(b.last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,b.row_count
      FROM  `<DATASETNAME>.__TABLES__` b WHERE table_id = CONCAT("ga_sessions_intraday_",FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE())))

      )

WHERE table_id = CONCAT("ga_sessions_intraday_",FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is not tested at all and is just based on [hopefully] correct shuffling your syntax around - so it avoids issue of "correlated subqueries that reference other tables"

```
UPDATE LOGGING.table_logs a
SET a.pinged = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS DATE,
    b.size_bytes,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(b.last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
    b.row_count
)
FROM  `<DATASETNAME>.__TABLES__` b 
WHERE a.table_id = b.table_id
AND a.table_id = CONCAT("ga_sessions_intraday_",FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()))
```

Please check and let me know if it works now or still some adjustments needed

P.S. Obviously, above assumes that the rest of logic is correct

> **Update for**: How do I retain what's already in a.pinged and update it with what is there currently plus the result of the query?

Try below

```
UPDATE LOGGING.table_logs a
SET a.pinged = ARRAY_CONCAT(a.pinged, ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT 
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS DATE,
    b.size_bytes,
    TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(b.last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,
    b.row_count
))
FROM  `<DATASETNAME>.__TABLES__` b 
WHERE a.table_id = b.table_id
AND a.table_id = CONCAT("ga_sessions_intraday_",FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()))
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail,
How do I retain what's already in a.pinged and update it with what is there currently plus the result of the query?

Comment: Ah yes it did work. You are the BQ Guru! I will break your code down and really understand what you did differently. Really appreciate you taking the time to look at this. I don't know how you get so good.

Comment: meantime, check update in my answer  - hopefully this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

I feel you might have overly simplified your query, which doesn't look correlated subquery to me, but in case you don't, my feeling is your subquery always generate same array regardless of which row LOGGING.table_logs has. You may be able to save the array first in a script variable and set it later:

```sql
DECLARE field_value DEFAULT 
ARRAY(
      (SELECT AS STRUCT 
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as date,b.size_bytes,timestamp_millis(b.last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time,b.row_count
      FROM  `<DATASETNAME>.__TABLES__` b WHERE table_id = CONCAT("ga_sessions_intraday_",FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()))));

UPDATE LOGGING.table_logs a
SET a.pinged = field_value
WHERE table_id = CONCAT("ga_sessions_intraday_",FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", CURRENT_DATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks Yun, I tried to modify the code above to retain the existing data and append the new data but I couldn't get it to work. Mikhail managed to get it working as expected but appreciate your help.